# Adding a back button for each bottom tab with React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

The bottom tabs navigation is looking something like that:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function TabStackScreen() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Favorites" component={FavoritesStackScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchStackScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}
```

There is not back button on the favorites and search screen. I guess this is the normal behavior, but I would love to have one.

I did not find something relevant in the doc, except recreating a component that looks like the native back button and adding it on some screens using headerLeft. Is there a more simple method?

Answer (score 2):

In my projects I like to create custom headers, and I do not show the default header and show my own custom header component.

On my custom component I add right and left components, and let the screens decide what to do, by default the back button is shown, but if the screen pass the ***noBack*** property, the button is hidden.

You can also add a right component, for example a close button.

That is what I use to do:

```
const screenOptions = {
  headerShown: false
};


<RootStack.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptions} mode="modal">
```

and then create my own component

```
export const Header = ({ title, leftComponent, rightComponent, noBack }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {leftComponent ||
        (noBack ? (
          <Placeholder />
        ) : (
          <Button
            onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
            accessible
            accessibilityRole="button"
            accessibilityLabel="Back">
            <Icon
              size={30}
              name={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'arrow-left' : 'chevron-left'}
            />
          </Button>
        ))}
      <Title bold accessibilityRole="header" acessible acessibilityText={title}>
        {title}
      </Title>
      {rightComponent || <Placeholder />}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

Doing that, you are able to customize everything on your header, it works like a charm for me.